# IoCreateSymbolicLink when it will return STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION

Tags: c, windows, device-driver

when I Call IoCreateSymbolicLink failing with status STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION.I have code in my driver where i tried to create symboliclink name between NT and DOS.

**When usually this error will cause?**

```
   RtlInitUnicodeString(

  &deviceName,

  L"\\Device\\StreamEitor"

  );


 RtlInitUnicodeString(

  &symbolicLinkName,

  L"\\DosDevices\\StreamEitor"

  );



   status = IoCreateDevice(

 driverObject, 

           0, 

           &deviceName, 

           FILE_DEVICE_NETWORK, 

           0, 

           FALSE, 

           &gDeviceObject

           );

   if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))

   {
  goto Exit;

   }

status = IoCreateSymbolicLink( &symbolicLinkName, &deviceName );


if ( !NT_SUCCESS( status )) {

    //IoDeleteDevice(ControlDeviceObject);

    DbgPrint("IoCreateSymbolicLink failed %x\n", status);

    goto Exit;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot destroy symbolic link using `IoDeleteSymbolicLink`.